# How to override FOSUserBundle ProfileFormType? -- Symfony 3.1

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, symfony

I've googled so many other options, and there are so many similar stack overflow questions that I've looked at, but they all dealt with outdated versions of Symfony or FOSUserBundle... It doesn't help that the FOSUserBundle documentation doesn't exactly cover how to add custom fields to the Profile page, only the registration page.

So how do I make custom fields I've added to the User class show up in the user's profile page? I've tried pretty much all other stack overflow attempts.

Here's my services.yml:

`services:
    app.profile.form.type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ProfileFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_profile }`

Here's my config.yml:

`fos_user:
    profile:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\ProfileFormType`

And just one iteration of many of my Profile class:

`<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;`

`use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;`

`class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildUserForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('pokemon');
    }`

```
public function getParent() 
{
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_user_profile';
}

// For Symfony 2.x
public function getName()
{
    return $this->getBlockPrefix();
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should extend the parent form class?

ProfileFormType extends \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType 
{
....
}

There is a parameter class (User entity) passed throught constructor

Answer (score 0):

In your profile class , the namespace is :namespace AppBundle\Form\Type
it means that you should put in your service :

```html
services:
    app.profile.form.type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_profile }
```

And make sure you are creation the folder type

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you have still this proble, but It's probably just the `buildUserForm`.

Change the method name to `buildForm`, with the `getParent()`, you'll get a `$builder` already filled with default FosUser fields in the `buildForm()` method.